# Android: No Activity found to handle Intent ( Download .xml file)

Tags: java, android

Crash after trigger download button that contains url to download .xml file

I am new in Android Development, i want to create a android app source from my web using webView but always crashing when i trying to download .xml file in emulator, can someone help me to correcting this code?

Error i face

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.webview, PID: 2422
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=//download:blob:http:mydownloadurl
```

```
import ...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView mWebView;



    String URL = "myWebsite"

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);


        //menghidupkan javascript
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(URL);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

        mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                        long contentLength) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("//download:"+url);
                Intent aIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
                startActivity(aIntent);
            }
        });

    }

    //method ini perlu ditambahkan agar saat halaman web diload tetap diload di aplikasi, tidak diload di webbrowseer
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {


        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed();
        }

    }

    //tambahkan method ini agar saat tombol back ditekan, tidak keluar dari aplikasi tapi kembali ke halaman sebelumnya
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: `Uri uri = Uri.parse("//download:"+url)` ??? What should that be? Please start with a valud url

Comment: If you catch that exception your app would not crash.

Comment: @blackapps im trying something before and forgot to delete that, any thanks! my app didnt crash anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this inside *onDownloadStart*:

```
Intent aIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
aIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(aIntent);
```

If that doesn't work, We can use DownloadManager to download content from url under *onDownloadStart*:

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "<<FileName>>");

DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
dm.enqueue(request);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Along with this permission in *AndroidManifest.xml* file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```